# time data does not match format in python

Tags: python

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: time data 'M/D/Y' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'
```

But I couldn't figure out where the problem is... Here is my code

```
def day(M, D, Y):
    day = datetime.datetime.strptime('M/D/Y', '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%A')
    return day
```

I've tried using `day(1, 12, 2017)` and `day(01, 12, 2017)` for month but when I used `01` I got a new error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line,

```
day = datetime.datetime.strptime('M/D/Y', '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%A')
```

`'M/D/Y'` is just a string, you can use [`str.format`](https://pyformat.info/), like this

```
day = datetime.datetime.strptime('{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(M, D, Y), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%A')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not making use of your function parameters correctly.

The parameters `M`, `D` and `Y` need to be used to construct a string, so (1, 12, 2017) becomes `1/12/2017`:

`day = datetime.datetime.strptime('{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(M, D, Y), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%A')`

Answer (score 0):

```
day = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/22/2017', '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%A')
```